# Pointing to XML entity declaration with relative path

Tags: xml, hibernate, entity, doctype, hibernate-mapping

I want to use [XML entites in my Hibernate mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcreate-polymorphism).

Here's my file structure:

```
/types/convertible-car.hbm.xml
/xml-entites/registration.xml
```

The mapping file `convertible-car.hbm.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" 
    [!ENTITY registration SYSTEM "../xml-entities/registration.xml"]>

<hibernate-mapping package="…">
    // …
    &registration;    
    // …
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The [XML entity](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlentity.php) `registration` is defined in the file `registration.xml`. Unfortunately I get this error when validating the Hibernate mapping file in Eclipse:

> The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
>   declaration must be well-formed.

I guess the error is caused by the parser not finding the `registration.xml` file. 
Do you know how I can embed an entity with a relative path?

Answer (score 1):

Your entity declaration is wrong. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-.0.dtd" [
<!ENTITY registration SYSTEM "../xml-entities/registration.xml">
]>
<hibernate-mapping package="…">
    // …
    &registration;    
    // …
</hibernate-mapping>
```